# Calculate sum of $\sum_{n=3} \frac{1}{4(n-2)}-\frac{1}{4(n+2)}$

Tags: telescopic-series

I have the following telescopic series:

$$\sum_{n=3} \frac{1}{4(n-2)}-\frac{1}{4(n+2)}$$

I want to calculate its sum. I'm assuming this is a telescopic series of the following type:

$$\sum_{n=1}{a_n-a_{a+k}}$$

So the sum should theoretically be $a_1 + a_2 + \dots + a_k$ with $k = 4$.

In this case, though, $n=3$, so how do I calculate the sum of this series? Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change index by replacing $k=n-2$ to get

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac 1{4k} - \frac 1{4(k+4)}$$

Is this more familiar now?

---

For more rigorous proof I would like you to refer to partial sums. Then as we have cancelation after the $4$ term we get:

$$S_N = \sum_{k=1}^{N} \frac 1{4k} - \frac 1{4(k+4)} = \frac 14 - \frac 1{20} + \frac 18 - \frac 1{24} + \frac 1{12} - \frac 1{28} + \frac 1{16} - \frac 1{32} + \frac{1}{20} - \frac{1}{36} + ... $$

$$+\frac 1{4N} - \frac 1{4(N+4)}= \frac 14 + \frac 18 + \frac 1{12} + \frac 1{16} - \frac 1{4(N+1)} - \frac 1{4(N+2)} - \frac 1{4(N+3)} - \frac{1}{4(N+3)}$$

Now we have that:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac 1{4k} - \frac 1{4(k+4)} = \lim_{N \to \infty} S_N = \frac 14 + \frac 18 + \frac 1{12} + \frac 1{16} = \frac{25}{48}$$

as the last four terms in $S_N$ tend to $0$, as $N \to \infty$

Comment: Thanks Stefan. The sum should now be $a_1$ which is equal to $\frac{1}{5}$. This is not the sum (should be $\frac{25}{48}$)

Comment: "The sum should now be a1" Huh? How so?

Comment: Since $k=1$ the sum should be $a_1 + \dots + a_k$?

Comment: @Cesare Yeah you're right. I added a more rigorous reasoning in the edit of my answer

Answer (score 0):

The sum is $ = \frac{1}{4}\left[1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}\right]$

Expand

$\frac{1}{1}\ -  \frac{1}{5}$

$\frac{1}{2}\ -  \frac{1}{6}$

$\frac{1}{3}\ -  \frac{1}{7}$

$\frac{1}{4}\ -  \frac{1}{8}$

$\frac{1}{5}\ -  \frac{1}{9}$

...

The $\frac{1}{5}$ in the first term cancels out with the  $\frac{1}{5}$ in the fifth term and hence forth all terms in the right gets cancelled to yeild the above.
$$ = \frac{25}{48}$$

Comment: Thanks. Where did you get 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4... from?

Comment: I have added explanation.  Did you downvote it?

Comment: I appreciate you adding an explanation. I did upvote. I did not downvote.

Comment: Thanks for very much.  Sorry, sometimes you provide the answer first and then explanation later.  Thanks again